# regex + shortest substring + word preceded by another word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the  following example

> "Foo tells bar that bar likes potato. Bar tells foo that bar does not
>   like potato."

I want the substring between potato and preceding occurrence of bar. So In this example, I want "bar likes potato" and also want "bar does not like potato" as the result. How can I achieve this through one regex? I know if I apply two separate regex I could get the results but I want to know if this is possible with only one regex.

Thanks,
RG

Comment: see ridgerunner answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word/15995332#15995332

Answer (score 3):

Nice riddle.  It can be solved, just not in a very nice way:

```
echo "Foo tells bar that bar likes potato. Bar tells foo that bar does not like potato." | \
    pcregrep  -o '\bbar\s+(?:(?:(?!bar\b)\w+)\s+)*?potato\b'
```

The outer `(?:...)` matches a word followed by a space.  The inner one makes sure said word is not `bar`.

Comment: Works as well. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea to separate words characters, (to follow the same idea you should replace `\s` with `\W` and add word boundaries at the begining and at the end.)

Comment: exclude "foobar ... potatoes" with \b

Comment: @Deadooshka Yes, edited.  I just didn't mean to obscure what's going one even more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `Python`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Foo tells bar that bar likes potato. Bar tells foo that bar does not like potato."
>>> re.findall('bar (?:(?! bar ).)+? potato', s)
['bar likes potato', 'bar does not like potato']
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Could you please explain how the inner loop "(?:(?! bar ).)" works in this case?

Comment: @user3669040 `(?:...)` is a non-capturing version of regular parentheses (parentheses is used for grouping). `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead assertion, i.e., `Isaac (?!Asimov)` will match `Isaac ` only if it’s not followed by `Asimov`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as the following perl snippet demonstrates:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str
  = "Foo tells bar that bar likes potato. "
  . "Bar tells foo that bar does not like potato."
;

while ($str =~ m/( bar (?: [^b] | b[^a] | ba[^r] )*?  potato )/xmsg) {
    print STDOUT "$1\n";
}
```

`*?` is a non-greedy quantifier (Match 0 or more times, not greedily; see Quantifiers at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Note that the alternatives `[^b] | b[^a] | ba[^r]` are mutually exclusive. The book "Mastering regular expressions" (http://regex.info/) is very instructive if you want to learn more about such constructions.

Comment: This works, but extending it to longer words gets increasingly complex.  You can avoid that with a negative lookahead, as I did in my answer.  The trick is to anchor the lookahead at both ends to make it effective.

Comment: It is true, your solution performs significantly better (about twice as fast). However, it does assume space-separated words (mine does not); since it is a likely assumption, I would prefer yours. It can be simplified a bit: `bar\s+(?>(?!bar\b)\w+\s+)*?potato`

Comment: @Loic: I will write it like this: `\bbar\W+(?:(?!bar\b)\w+\W+)*?potato\b` *(atomic group is not needed for backtracking considerations since you advance with a lazy quantifier)*

Comment: @Loic: Yes, for my solution it's essential to have something to use as anchors at both ends of the negative lookahead, that's the real crux of the matter.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: It is not true, non-greedy quantification does not ensure that the quantified group is handled atomically. For instance, the string `"aa"` is accepted by `(?:a*)*?a` but not by `(?>a*)*?a`; thus backtracking happens with the first regexp. In general, I prefer to avoid nested quantifications wherever possible, because they may have poor performance on pathological inputs (not always, but there is still a risk).

Comment: Indeed It can backtrack on spaces or non word characters when "patato" is not in the string , so writing: `\bbar\W+(?:(?!bar\b)\w+\W++)*?potato\b` solves the problem. About "nested quantifications", you indeed need to be carefull but using systematically atomic groups or possessive quantifiers, or writing patterns designed for grep: `(a|b|c)*` is a bad idea. (with a backtracking engine the last one can be terrible) You need to take all in account: how looks the string, what contains the repeated group, if it is an always true subpattern, the character classes, etc.